# getting wrong results in count function while using group by clause in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

im calculating how many  links are submitted in each categories. i have assigned four categories -Classifieds,Events,Articles,Socialbookmarking for monday . user submitted 15 links in classified category . but it showing 15*4 = 60 links submitted.
output getting like this

```
Categoryname    DayTarget   LnkSubmsnDate   LnkSubmtdBy submittedLinks  performance
Classifieds         15        10/12/2015        swapna       60             Reached
```

but i want like this

```
 Categoryname   DayTarget   LnkSubmsnDate   LnkSubmtdBy submittedLinks  performance
  Classifieds   15       10/12/2015       swapna         15             Reached
  Events        2        10/12/2015       swapna         0              not Reached
  Articles      2        10/12/2015        swapna         0             not Reached
Socialbookmarking 10     10/12/2015        swapna         0             not Reached
```

sql query

```
select c.Categoryname,DayTarget,l.LnkSubmsnDate,l.LnkSubmtdBy,COUNT(LinkId) as submittedLinks,
   (CASE
  WHEN DayTarget=COUNT(LinkId)     THEN 'Reached'  
  WHEN DayTarget-COUNT(LinkId)   < 1  THEN 'Reached' 
  WHEN DayTarget-COUNT(LinkId)  >= 1 THEN 'Not Reached' 
END ) as performance
   from tbl_Link as l
    join Tbl_DaySubmission ds on l.ProjectId=ds.projectid and l.CategoryId=ds.CatId 
    join tbl_Category c on l.CategoryId=c.CategoryId
    where LnkSubmsnDate='2015-10-12'and l.ProjectId='109'
    group by c.Categoryname,ds.DayTarget,LnkSubmsnDate,l.LnkSubmtdBy
```

table definations

```
TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_DaySubmission](
    [DayId] [bigint] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
    [DayName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DayNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CatId] [int] NULL,
    [DayTarget] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [status] [bit] NULL
```

**tbl_link**

```
TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Link](
    [LinkId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LinkName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ReportLinks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NULL,
    [KeywordID] [int] NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NULL,
    [LnkSubmsnDate] [date] NULL,
    [LnkSubmtdBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
```

tbl_category

```
TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Category](
    [CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Categoryname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
```

Comment: What is your current query?  And it would not hurt to also include your table definitions.

Comment: Are you sure your table has more than one category?

Comment: yes i have table with  more than 1 category.but user has not submitted any links on that category.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting answers in multiples of the expected value, it means that your join is not working properly (Data is not as you expected in one of the table).

We cannot guide you without seeing the actual data in all of the tables as you are not using the primary keys to join tables.

I would suggest you to break your query into multiple steps and evaluate the result at each step before joining with another table and that would help you in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve LnkSubmsnDate and LnkSubmtdBy from unsubmitted tbl_Links. You have to set default values to the 2 columns if they are unsubmitted, otherwise they show null.

```
SELECT
c.Categoryname
, ds.DayTarget 
, CASE WHEN (COUNT(LinkId) > 0) THEN l.LnkSubmsnDate
ELSE NULL END AS [LnkSubmsnDate]
, CASE WHEN (COUNT(LinkId) > 0) THEN l.LnkSubmtdBy
ELSE NULL END AS [LnkSubmtdBy]
, COUNT(LinkId) AS submittedLinks
, (CASE
  WHEN DayTarget=COUNT(LinkId)     THEN 'Reached'  
  WHEN DayTarget-COUNT(LinkId)   < 1  THEN 'Reached' 
  WHEN DayTarget-COUNT(LinkId)  >= 1 THEN 'Not Reached' 
END ) AS performance
FROM tbl_Category AS c
INNER JOIN Tbl_DaySubmission AS ds ON ds.CatId = c.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_Link WHERE LnkSubmsnDate='2015-10-12') AS l ON l.ProjectId = ds.ProjectID AND l.CategoryId = ds.CatId
WHERE ds.ProjectID = 109
GROUP BY c.Categoryname, ds.DayTarget, l.LnkSubmsnDate, l.LnkSubmtdBy
ORDER BY performance DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/548a26/7

Comment: its giving redundancy. records

Comment: Sorry for frequent revising! I've edited my query to another version.

Comment: ya its working . lets see what happens after going to live.